# How can i copy a file (.bacpac) from aAzure storage to AWS S3 Standard bit bucket using PowerShell?

Tags: amazon-web-services, azure, powershell

I have a .bacpac file in Azure storage. I have an AWS account. I want to copy this file, the .bacpac in Azure  to an AWS standard S3 bit bucket using Powershell's az cli commands.
Do i  need to login Azure asw well as AWS to establish a connection .

How can i do this copy using Az cli ?

Comment: The az cli commands aren't PowerShell commands, however there is an Azure PowerShell module (`AzureRM`). There is also an AWS S3 powershell module ( [`AWS.Tools.S3`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/powershell/latest/userguide/pstools-s3.html) ) as well as a non-powershell [`aws s3`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3/) CLI tool. Whether you use the powershell cmds or the cli tools is up to you, but to answer your question you can download the file from azure using `az storage blob download` then upload to AWS S3 using `aws s3api put-object`.

Comment: So do i need to download to local stoarage like c:\ drive and then to AWS ?  I thought i could go straight from Azure , get the file and upload to AWS using az cli cmds or azcopy ?  I assume i need to install aws cmds in Windows Powershell ISE ?

Comment: do you have examples of the above commands ?

Comment: The only way I know of is to download to your local storage then up to S3. [This article](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/modernizing-with-aws/azure-blob-to-amazon-s3/) describes how you can set up a system to copy from Azure to S3. With some quick googling I found [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/storage/blob?view=azure-cli-latest#az-storage-blob-download-examples) are examples for the `az storage blob download` and [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3api/put-object.html#examples) are examples for `aws s3api put-object`.

Comment: fyi this question probably fits better on [sf] - it's not a programming question and is off-topic here.

Answer (score 0):

> How can I copy a file (.bacpac) from Azure storage to AWS S3 Standard bit bucket using PowerShell?

As of now, there is no direct command to copy files from Azure Blob storage to AWS.

I agree with Jeremywat's comment that you need to download files to local storage and then upload files from local to AWS.

For downloading all files like (.bacpac) from Azure Blob storage to the local environment, you can use the command below.

**Command:**

```
az storage blob download-batch --source <container-name> --destination <local path> --pattern "*.bacpac" --account-name <storage-account-name> --account-key <storage-account-key>  2>$null
```

[image]

Here, I download all .mp4 files to the local environment from Azure Blob storage.

To upload **`.bacpac`** files from local to the AWS S3 bucket, you can use the command below.

**Command:**

```
aws s3 cp my-files s3://my-bucket/ --recursive
```

**Reference:**

[Upload Files to AWS S3 using CLI](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-upload-files-to-aws-s3-using-cli/)